# Symfony3 repository method doesn't work

Tags: php, repository, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to call a method in the repository ArticleRepository from my controller ArticleController. However it says :

```
Undefined method 'afficheArticle'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

my Entity Article : (Entity\Article.php)

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Article", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="I_FK_Article_TypeArticle", columns={"idTypeArticle"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="erp-gkeep\new_erp\gkeepBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
```

my ArticleController (Controller\ArticleController)

```
 /**
     * @Route("viewArticle2", name="viewArticle2")
     */
    public function listAction2()
    {

        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('gkeepBundle:Article')->afficheArticle();
```

my ArticleRepository

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */

namespace gkeepBundle\Repository;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function afficheArticle(){
        $em=$this->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT a.reference, a.designationfr, a.designationen, a.plan, a.url, a.datecreation, a.idtypearticle
     FROM gkeepBundle:Article a
     '
        );

        $articles = $query->getArrayResult();

        return $articles;
    }
}
```

if someone can help me please ! I'm pretty sure it's a stupid error :/

Answer (score 0):

The value of `repositoryClass` in your mapping annotation needs to be the namespace + class name of your repository, it looks like you've maybe added some of the directory structure as well. `-` actually isn't a valid character in a PHP namespace, so the value you've got now definitely isn't right.

Try

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="gkeepBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
```

For reference: when this classname is not valid, Doctrine falls back to the default repository - this is what's throwing the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi @iainn, thanks for your help ! I had already tried your answer but no positive result, I've still the same error message :/

Comment: By the way I created myself the directory "Repository" and the class "ArticleRepository.php" maybe it change something and that's why the logiciel doesn't recognize the repository ?

Comment: try to check the spelling and clean cache